# Ads Banner not Display

Tags: java, android, admob, logcat

When i test my project in emulator the Interstitial ads work fine but there is an error on Logcat for banner ads like this

```
09-26 10:36:52.728: W/Ads(787): JS: The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&pan_include=0&request_id=df9e7124-c7b5-4a32-8882-ff5b6d171601&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D17084132833272238065%26seq_num%3D3%26rm%3D2%26fdz%3D-1%26adtest%3Don%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v7895000.7895000.0%26hl%3Den%26submodel%3Dsdk%26gnt%3D3%26ma%3D0%26carrier%3D310260%26capability%3D%255Bobject%2520Object%255D%26platform%3Dunknown%26u_sd%3D1.5%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D0%26muv%3D11%26riv%3D5%26ms%3DIawFRMvoW4tm731P_cxUADnFxcsMFq8w40vkDEA6SiDoPbmtTQQt1dCnPTXg7LKHIjgoVYr0IfZVvxTV1dBRqS2s2adMkMDxwk2Hfoun1ppwTFSHoEt3pgbHRlv5G4adk24fTrSuCey40Ut10J97z3wXHhBU-bVJNpaZiPQVWt5eAdY5qRUZCu1_e0k8c15nkOWPCs8hUqFOlK77Ov108auaOX9pHs7PC8fQyvFO-XlX2ms3-uCsDIPwDo3tPrXYH4wM7X7Yhfp2jKkeOkekmsi322Ot8jZ8x8do6jksRrFAbg8sp0c3_mN2Ytbfao3Bw8PgWTJJDKkalWs7icdyPA%26format%3D320x50_mb%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DUS%26request_id%3Ddf9e7124-c7b5-4a32-8882-ff5b6d171601%26am%3D0%26cap%3Dm%26u_w%3D320%26u_h%3D534%26msid%3Dcom.mira.canyoutapit%26app_name%3D1.android.com.mira.canyoutapit%26an%3D1.android.com.mira.canyoutapit%26net%3Ded%26u_audio%3D4%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D2%26support_transparent_background%3Dtrue%26pimp%3D1%26currts%3D303435%26basets%3D207427%26pclick%3D0%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D420%26client_sdk%3D1%26ex%3D1%26client%3Dca-app-pub-3940256099942544%26slotname%3D6300978111%26askip%3D2%26gsb%3D3g%26bisch%3Dfalse%26blev%3D0%26swdr%3Dfalse%26cans%3D5%26canm%3Dtrue%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_th_autoplay_mediation_av_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26_efs%3Dfalse%26forceHttps%3Dtrue%26blockAutoClicks%3D0%26forceGmsDoritos%3D1%26eid%3D46621136%26tcar%3D157%26jsv%3D188%26urll%3D1314&base_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma&use_webview_loadurl=0&enable_auto_click_protection=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1443238612644.
09-26 10:41:21.668: I/Ads(787): Starting ad request.
09-26 10:41:21.988: D/dalvikvm(787): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1987K, 9% free 21461K/23559K, paused 49ms+30ms, total 184ms
09-26 10:41:23.228: W/Ads(787): JS: The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&pan_include=0&request_id=5a59999f-8b9e-4b94-aa81-a114ddbcb8f3&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D17084132833272238065%26seq_num%3D7%26rm%3D2%26fdz%3D-1%26adtest%3Don%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v7895000.7895000.0%26hl%3Den%26submodel%3Dsdk%26gnt%3D3%26ma%3D0%26carrier%3D310260%26capability%3D%255Bobject%2520Object%255D%26platform%3Dunknown%26u_sd%3D1.5%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D0%26muv%3D11%26riv%3D5%26ms%3Du3iwBlSpMFdNir0aPUZWwoVidHVXmtgPmqcc9xbnauPMLfW1J7Y8Tg7rzEGoK8O00Qh9tUOFUax9o-DL9an4MVLCLdjBpb6bLn2_HuTYzYZTvzcFjzwIQT4tv0tZVej7aKJSc2f-W1J6Vp8OIUdPeSWQ9B4pAlV2F0XsPcxBS_uPyutqamcHPea29F2R5EkV5SAGruJQ6k3atKBVjBsE8zDlZt47-9ZHUTGNp-Vc7gOuJda-iFW6rsiaZFxFwPNqNW2RVQENDsBbPclQq2359XIMACcfwNPi5_2aR-2hSxk5TkAFF-hZw0KSj3NPXZNst9XYlsvLdS1TpbX4Acoazw%26format%3D320x50_mb%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DUS%26request_id%3D5a59999f-8b9e-4b94-aa81-a114ddbcb8f3%26am%3D0%26ad_x%3D5%26ad_y%3D720%26ad_w%3D470%26ad_h%3D75%26ad_v%3D1%26cap%3Dm%26u_w%3D320%26u_h%3D534%26msid%3Dcom.mira.canyoutapit%26app_name%3D1.android.com.mira.canyoutapit%26an%3D1.android.com.mira.canyoutapit%26net%3Ded%26u_audio%3D4%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D6%26support_transparent_background%3Dtrue%26pimp%3D5%26currts%3D578374%26basets%3D207427%26pclick%3D0%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D420%26client_sdk%3D1%26ex%3D1%26client%3Dca-app-pub-3940256099942544%26slotname%3D6300978111%26askip%3D1%26gsb%3D3g%26bisch%3Dfalse%26blev%3D0%26swdr%3Dfalse%26cans%3D5%26canm%3Dtrue%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_th_autoplay_mediation_av_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26_efs%3Dfalse%26forceHttps%3Dtrue%26blockAutoClicks%3D0%26forceGmsDoritos%3D1%26eid%3D46621136%26tcar%3D87%26jsv%3D188%26urll%3D1353&base_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma&use_webview_loadurl=0&enable_auto_click_protection=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1443238883148.
09-26 10:41:23.228: W/Ads(787):  (null:1)
09-26 10:41:23.228: W/Web Console(787): The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&pan_include=0&request_id=5a59999f-8b9e-4b94-aa81-a114ddbcb8f3&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D17084132833272238065%26seq_num%3D7%26rm%3D2%26fdz%3D-1%26adtest%3Don%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v7895000.7895000.0%26hl%3Den%26submodel%3Dsdk%26gnt%3D3%26ma%3D0%26carrier%3D310260%26capability%3D%255Bobject%2520Object%255D%26platform%3Dunknown%26u_sd%3D1.5%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D0%26muv%3D11%26riv%3D5%26ms%3Du3iwBlSpMFdNir0aPUZWwoVidHVXmtgPmqcc9xbnauPMLfW1J7Y8Tg7rzEGoK8O00Qh9tUOFUax9o-DL9an4MVLCLdjBpb6bLn2_HuTYzYZTvzcFjzwIQT4tv0tZVej7aKJSc2f-W1J6Vp8OIUdPeSWQ9B4pAlV2F0XsPcxBS_uPyutqamcHPea29F2R5EkV5SAGruJQ6k3atKBVjBsE8zDlZt47-9ZHUTGNp-Vc7gOuJda-iFW6rsiaZFxFwPNqNW2RVQENDsBbPclQq2359XIMACcfwNPi5_2aR-2hSxk5TkAFF-hZw0KSj3NPXZNst9XYlsvLdS1TpbX4Acoazw%26format%3D320x50_mb%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DUS%26request_id%3D5a59999f-8b9e-4b94-aa81-a114ddbcb8f3%26am%3D0%26ad_x%3D5%26ad_y%3D720%26ad_w%3D470%26ad_h%3D75%26ad_v%3D1%26cap%3Dm%26u_w%3D320%26u_h%3D534%26msid%3Dcom.mira.canyoutapit%26app_name%3D1.android.com.mira.canyoutapit%26an%3D1.android.com.mira.canyoutapit%26net%3Ded%26u_audio%3D4%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D6%26support_transparent_background%3Dtrue%26pimp%3D5%26currts%3D578374%26basets%3D207427%26pclick%3D0%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D420%26client_sdk%3D1%26ex%3D1%26client%3Dca-app-pub-3940256099942544%26slotname%3D6300978111%26askip%3D1%26gsb%3D3g%26bisch%3Dfalse%26blev%3D0%26swdr%3Dfalse%26cans%3D5%26canm%3Dtrue%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_th_autoplay_mediation_av_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26_efs%3Dfalse%26forceHttps%3Dtrue%26blockAutoClicks%3D0%26forceGmsDoritos%3D1%26eid%3D46621136%26tcar%3D87%26jsv%3D188%26urll%3D1353&base_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma&use_webview_loadurl=0&enable_auto_click_protection=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1443238883148.
09-26 10:41:23.228: W/Web Console(787):  at null:1
09-26 10:41:23.228: W/Ads(787):  (null:1)
09-26 10:41:23.228: W/Web Console(787): The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&pan_include=0&request_id=5a59999f-8b9e-4b94-aa81-a114ddbcb8f3&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D17084132833272238065%26seq_num%3D7%26rm%3D2%26fdz%3D-1%26adtest%3Don%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v7895000.7895000.0%26hl%3Den%26submodel%3Dsdk%26gnt%3D3%26ma%3D0%26carrier%3D310260%26capability%3D%255Bobject%2520Object%255D%26platform%3Dunknown%26u_sd%3D1.5%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D0%26muv%3D11%26riv%3D5%26ms%3Du3iwBlSpMFdNir0aPUZWwoVidHVXmtgPmqcc9xbnauPMLfW1J7Y8Tg7rzEGoK8O00Qh9tUOFUax9o-DL9an4MVLCLdjBpb6bLn2_HuTYzYZTvzcFjzwIQT4tv0tZVej7aKJSc2f-W1J6Vp8OIUdPeSWQ9B4pAlV2F0XsPcxBS_uPyutqamcHPea29F2R5EkV5SAGruJQ6k3atKBVjBsE8zDlZt47-9ZHUTGNp-Vc7gOuJda-iFW6rsiaZFxFwPNqNW2RVQENDsBbPclQq2359XIMACcfwNPi5_2aR-2hSxk5TkAFF-hZw0KSj3NPXZNst9XYlsvLdS1TpbX4Acoazw%26format%3D320x50_mb%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DUS%26request_id%3D5a59999f-8b9e-4b94-aa81-a114ddbcb8f3%26am%3D0%26ad_x%3D5%26ad_y%3D720%26ad_w%3D470%26ad_h%3D75%26ad_v%3D1%26cap%3Dm%26u_w%3D320%26u_h%3D534%26msid%3Dcom.mira.canyoutapit%26app_name%3D1.android.com.mira.canyoutapit%26an%3D1.android.com.mira.canyoutapit%26net%3Ded%26u_audio%3D4%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D6%26support_transparent_background%3Dtrue%26pimp%3D5%26currts%3D578374%26basets%3D207427%26pclick%3D0%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D420%26client_sdk%3D1%26ex%3D1%26client%3Dca-app-pub-3940256099942544%26slotname%3D6300978111%26askip%3D1%26gsb%3D3g%26bisch%3Dfalse%26blev%3D0%26swdr%3Dfalse%26cans%3D5%26canm%3Dtrue%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_th_autoplay_mediation_av_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26_efs%3Dfalse%26forceHttps%3Dtrue%26blockAutoClicks%3D0%26forceGmsDoritos%3D1%26eid%3D46621136%26tcar%3D87%26jsv%3D188%26urll%3D1353&base_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma&use_webview_loadurl=0&enable_auto_click_protection=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1443238883148.
09-26 10:42:27.318: W/Web Console(787):  at null:1
09-26 10:42:27.368: W/Ads(787): JS: The page at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.
09-26 10:42:27.368: W/Ads(787):  (null:1)
09-26 10:42:27.368: W/Web Console(787): The page at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.
09-26 10:42:27.368: W/Web Console(787):  at null:1
09-26 10:42:29.368: D/webviewglue(787): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a44c060
09-26 10:42:29.538: I/Ads(787): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
09-26 10:42:29.678: I/Ads(787): Ad finished loading.
09-26 10:42:29.678: I/Choreographer(787): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-26 10:42:29.688: W/Ads(787): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 313x526 dp.
09-26 10:42:29.688: W/Ads(787): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 313x526 dp.
09-26 10:42:30.008: D/dalvikvm(787): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1940K, 9% free 21486K/23559K, paused 50ms+48ms, total 353ms
09-26 10:43:29.548: I/Ads(787): Starting ad request.
```

and this is my xml data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundblankyellow"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearFailed"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/imageheadbackblack" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/backgroundfailed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/imagepopup"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imagenewbesttap"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/imageplaynewhighscore"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textbesttap"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="BEST TAP"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="italic|bold"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/besttap"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textSize="50sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/texttapped"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="CURRENT"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="italic|bold"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/currenttap"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textSize="50sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/imageunder"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonrestart"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="25dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonrestart" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonmenu"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="25dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonmenu" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/imageheadbackblack" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/imageheadbackblack"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totaltap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/besttotaltap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rulesimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/playimage"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/playlinear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundplay"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yellow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonyellowflash"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/imageheadbackblack"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/countdowntext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </FrameLayout>

     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
         android:id="@+id/adView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

</LinearLayout>
```

anyone can help me with this problem? how to fix the error that make ads not display?

Thank's in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in log-cat belongs to BANNER ad in your xml file i.e. `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`. It is not related to Interstitial ads.

The error occurred because, in your layout, there is not much room for ad to load. See following message from error logcat

> Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 313x526 dp.

Redesign your layout and make sure `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` have enough height for loading content.

Comment: so did i just change weight to 320 and height to 50?

Comment: Yes, you can provide height width. Sorry i confused BANNER with SMART_BANNER

Comment: i changed w to 320 and h to 50 but its not allowed

Comment: Create a layout with 320x50 width & height and put Admob layout in it. Make Admob's height & width to wrapcontent